# nginx always adding trailing slash after domain

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I've spent forever searching and I can't see that I'm doing anything wrong.

Basically I have two domains and want to route to a backend service depending on which one is visited.

- clientkey.local
- clientkey.strapi.local

When I visit each of these domains, it's rewriting the urls as:

- clientkey.local/
- clientkey.strapi.local/

There is no point to adding the extra slashes if I'm just visiting the base domain. I can add the trailing slash if I want and still end up on the home page, but it shouldn't redirect me there automatically. Below is my nginx config.

Any ideas? I'm using docker-compose if that matters. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http { 
    upstream strapi_servers {
        server strapi:1337;
    }

    upstream gallery_servers {
        server gallery;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name clientkey.strapi.local;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://strapi_servers;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name clientkey.local;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://gallery_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is no point to adding the extra slashes if I'm just visiting the base domain" - with `/` you're requesting domain/site root. Without - you're seeking to request emptiness? I think there's no such thing as requesting "just the domain". You must be requesting *some URI* on it.

Comment: Sure, then why if you go to stackoverflow.com it doesnt show stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: It's only a display matter. Browser doesn't show the slash, but it's actually requesting the root of the domain, which is `/`. It can't request "nothing" from the domain/host.

Comment: I think your question would be rather why the browser is showing slash in one case (your domains) while not showing it in the other. But I don't think the underlying server logic is different (there is always slash request, because empty request is impossible). To confirm my thinking see [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser).

Comment: My browser is showing the slash though. I suspect it has something to do with my hosts file. I'm setting 127.0.0.1 clientkey.local in my hosts file. No slash appears in my browser when I visit 'localhost' but it does show the slash when I go to clientkey.local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick testing reveals that slash is not hidden for non-public TLD websites (Chromium/Chrome).

In other words, if the TLD isn't real, then slash is not being ommited.

- example.local - slash shown
- example.anyting-non-real - slash shown
- example.com - slash hidden

Comment: Confirmed, thanks. Changed my host file and it's now resolved.